# How can I configure maven resources plugin with a few copy tasks?

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have two copy tasks that I want to do with maven-resources-plugin. For example I need to copy `config.yml` from `src/main/resources` to root folder and to copy all folder contents from `/src/main/resources/examples` to `src/examples`.

```
root
  /src
    /main
      /resources   --> config.yml (to root)
        /examples  --> all folder contents (to /src/examples)
```

The only one solution I've found is this:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/config.yml</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
                <!-- <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/examples</directory>
                </resource> -->
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

but I can add only one destination folder.

Comment: why do you copy it to src/* ? you should be using target folder. Anyway you cam create another execution with different ID and configuration

Comment: That's a good idea about another execution phase, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another execution with different ID and configuration:

```
<execution>
    <id>copy-resources-2</id>
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
</execution>
```